# Настройка webpack 4 при помощи typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack4

Настраиваю проект и столкнулся с проблемой, если настройки для `webpack` прописывать в `webpack.config.ts` файле после запуска команды `webpack` появляется портянка ошибок.
Ранее был опыт настройки `gulp` на typescript и там `gulp` самостоятельно находил установленный `ts-node` и запускался через него.
Как настроить webpack 4 без промежуточного компилирования конфига из `.ts в .js`?

Node.js: v8.10.0
Npm: 5.6.0
Webpack: 4.1.1
OS: KDE-neon 5.12.3

Comment: А какой в этом смысл если по большей части конфиг webpack-а - это объект?

Comment: @Zhukov Roman Может это трата времени, но мне хочется разобраться с этим вопросом, что бы в будущем я уже знал как его решить, и возможно это еще кому нибудь пригодится.

Comment: а то, что в официальной документации - не работает? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-languages/

Comment: @ Zhukov Roman Странно, попробовал воспроизвести все что делал дома на рабочем компе с такой же системой, все работает как я хотел.

Comment: @Zhukov Roman можете оформить ваш коммент как ответ, если хотите.